# THEORY OF EQUATIONS

Tags: polynomials

I would like to solve this problem:

> If $a$ is a special root of the equation $x^8-1=0$, then prove that
>   $$1+3a+5a^2+7a^3+....+15a^7=16/(a-1)$$

Comment: Please, show your attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$S=\sum_{r=0}^7(2r+1)a^r$$

$$a\cdot S=\cdots$$

$$\implies(1-a)S=1+2(a+a^2+\cdots+a^7)-15a^8=1-15a^8+2\cdot\dfrac{a(a^7-1)}{a-1}$$

Now use $a^8=1$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: let LHS=$f(a)$, then what is $af(a)-f(a)$?

Answer (score 0):

$(a-1)(1+3a+...+15a^7)=a+3a^2+..+15a^8-1-3a-...-15a^7=15-1-2a-2a^2...-2a^7=16-2(1+a+...+a^7)=16$.